# how to solve predict.lm() error: variable 'affinity' was fitted with type "nmatrix.1" but type "numeric" was supplied

Tags: r, predict

I have a simple linear model:

```
mylm = lm(formula = prodRate~affinity, mydf)
```

where mydf is a dataframe which looks like:

```
 prodRate    affinity

1  2643.5744 0.005164040

2  2347.6923 0.004439970

3  1783.6819 0.003322830
```

when I use predict.lm() an error came up:

```
my_pred= predict(mylm,newdata=data.frame(affinity=seq(0,1,0.1)) )
```

Error: variable 'affinity' was fitted with type "nmatrix.1" but type "numeric" was supplied.

Why is that? how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: This is likely due to how you created your mydf dataframe. See this post https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-August/170848.html

Comment: I actually read that post but did not understand what is wrong with mydf, which is a normal dataframe with two columns with names "prodRate" and "affinity". Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: Can you post str(mydf) please

Comment: str(mydf)
'data.frame': 16 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ prodRate: num  2644 2348 1784 1685 1416 ...
 $ affinity: num [1:16, 1] 0.00516 0.00444 0.00332 0.00307 0.00271 ...

Comment: ok, so affinity is added to the dataframe as a [16,1] matrix rather than a vector (my terms may be a bit off). Did you create the dataframe with mydf$affinity <- matrix(somenumbers). Try creating it with mydf <- data.frame(prodRate , affinity).

Comment: Or a quick fix: wrap your affinity in your lm call in as.vector(affinity) ie. mylm <- lm(formula = prodRate ~ as.vector(affinity), mydf)

Comment: That is exactly what happened! I am so glad that the problem is solved. Thank you so so much!

Comment: your very welcome. Perhaps write up an answer and accept it for future readers.

Comment: sure will do. Thank you very much for promoting a culture of serving the common good, which is much needed in this hour.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to the discussion with user20650 (see above), the bug was identified:

The mydf in `mylm = lm(formula = prodRate~affinity, mydf)` was created by adding an matrix-like column to the existed dataframe mydf as following:

`mydf$affinity = matrix(somenumber)`

i.e. the "affinity" column in mydf is made from a matrix and its structure remains as matrix.
This matrix structure is NOT consistent with the "affinity" column in `newdata=data.frame(affinity=seq(0,1,0.1))` in `predict(mylm,newdata=...)`, which is a numeric vector.

solution1: fix mydf as following
 `mydf <- data.frame(prodRate , affinity)`.
i.e. make sure that the affinity column of mydf has a vector-like structure

solution2: keep the original mydf but enforce mydf$affinity as vector in the fomular:
`mylm <- lm(formula = prodRate ~ as.vector(affinity), mydf)`
so that the independent variable "affinity" in the linear model "mylm" has the vector-like structure instead of matrix-like structure, which will be consistent with the `newdata=data.frame(affinity=seq(0,1,0.1))` in `predict(mylm,newdata=...)`, which is a numeric vector.