# Error in setting up and cleaning a dataframe R

Tags: r

I am attempting to generate out of sample predictions and am getting this message after running the following code `Error: variable 'dummygen' was fitted with type "numeric" but type "factor" was supplied`.

I checked the `str` to verify that the two variables I am using are both numeric and they appear to be. I did a bunch of hunting around on here and think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337495/how-to-solve-predict-lm-error-variable-affinity-was-fitted-with-type-nmatr) might be somewhat related, but I haven't been able to get the suggestions to work.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
library(foreign)
library(plyr)
library(rvest)
library(stringi)
library(purrr)
library(XLConnect)
library(splitstackshape)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

donner_raw <- read.csv("donner.txt", sep="\t", header = FALSE) 
colnames(donner_raw) <- c("age_gen", "survive")

donner_raw <- separate(donner_raw, age_gen, into = c("age", "gender"), "(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Za-z])")

logit <- glm(survive ~ age + dummygen,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=donner_raw)

newlogit <- data.frame(age=seq(1,6, length=20), dummygen=("0"))
ooslogit <- predict.glm(logit, newlogit, se.fit=TRUE)
```

I'm not sure where in the process of what I've done I messed up. Here is a reproducible part of the data.

```
dput(droplevels(head(donner_raw)))
structure(list(age = structure(c(6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("13", "3", "4", "45", "6", "60"), class = "factor"), gender = c("M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), dummygen = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("age", "gender", "survive", "dummygen"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Just change the class of the variable in the prediction data to make it match. You can use `as.numeric`. There's something wrong with the `dput` but you can see that the class is `factor` in it. Just change the class.

Comment: @SamMarshal Read my answer.

Comment: why did you delete your last post and repost this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simply read and think about the error message:

> Error: variable 'dummygen' was fitted with type "numeric" but type "factor" was supplied

This error occurs after the line:

```
ooslogit <- predict.glm(logit, newlogit, se.fit=TRUE)
```

(Presumably, at least, because you're question isn't very clear about this and provides lots of code that doesn't seem related.)

So R is telling you that when the model was *fit* the variable `dummygen` was numeric, but *now* you've given it a factor.

So let's look:

```
str(newlogit)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ age     : num  1 1.26 1.53 1.79 2.05 ...
 $ dummygen: Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Yep!

So your problem was that you inexplicably created the data frame `newlogit` by specifying:

```
newlogit <- data.frame(age=seq(1,6, length=20), dummygen=("0"))
```

which *clearly* specifies that the variable `dummygen` is not going to be numeric. Just convert it back, or remove the quotes in the first place. For example:

```
newlogit <- data.frame(age=seq(1,6, length=20), dummygen= 0)
```

or

```
newlogit$dummygen <- as.numeric(newlogit$dummygen)
```

Comment: The problem was the " ". That is incredibly annoying and more so since I've spent 6 hours on this. Thank you VERY much for walking me through the logic. That is definitely a mistake I hopefully will never make again!