# How to fix error: variable 'exper' was fitted with type "character" but type "numeric" was supplied

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to construct a dataframe. Here:

```
newdata1 = data.frame(exper=1, exper2=1*1, exper3=1*1*1, union=1, school=1)
```

And then when I want to predict, using:

```
log_wage1 = predict(reg, newdata=newdata1)
```

the error occurs. I tried using:

```
newdata1$exper = as.integer(newdata1$exper)
```

but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me to fix it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please show structure of the data and the model output you're using to predict. What is the error that occurs?

Comment: Maria, this is a similar problem with a good answer on how to chase/isolate the problem (and then fix it): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431938/error-in-setting-up-and-cleaning-a-dataframe-r.     In short the error tells you that you fitted a model (previously) with type character. And (now) you provide a numeric variable.           You will also find more friends here, if you provide a `minimal reproducible example` (i.e. a few rows/values of your data). This allows to check where things go wrong or reproduce the behaviour / problems you face. Good luck.