# Error when using predict() function with linear regression model in R: Error variable was fitted with type "nmatrix.1" but type "numeric" was supplied

Tags: r

I get an error while trying to use the predict() function with a linear regression model in R. The goal is to predict values for a new dataset based on the trained model. However, I'm consistently getting an error related to the variable type. I want to extract values from a ndvi-raster and predict AboveGroundBiomass values based on the linear model with ground truth data

I have calculated the ndvi from a satellite raster for my sample points and added them as a new column to my groundtruth data frame. I divided this data frame into training and testing data frame and then trained a model and predicted the agb values for my sample points which worked fine:

```
model_lr <- lm(AGB ~ NDVI_mean, data = training_df)
predictions_lr <- predict(model_lr, newdata = testing_df)
```

However, when I try to predict the values for my entire ndvi raster (shape of satellite image) by extracting all values from the ndvi raster:

```
entire_ndvi_mean <- raster::extract(ndvi_raster, aoi)

newdata <- data.frame(NDVI_mean = entire_ndvi_mean)

colnames(newdata) <- c("NDVI_mean")

entire_predictions <- predict(model_lr, newdata = newdata)
```

I get this error while predicting:

> `Error: variable 'NDVI_mean' was fitted with type "nmatrix.1" but type "numeric" was supplied`

Maybe just as an information:

```
> class(model_lr$terms$variables$NDVI_mean)
[1] "NULL"

> class(newdata$NDVI_mean)
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: You could try `lm(AGB ~ as.vector(NDVI_mean), data = training_df)` (note the `as.vector`), as suggested in these comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337495/how-to-solve-predict-lm-error-variable-affinity-was-fitted-with-type-nmatr